# how to change month in 'numbers' to month in 'name' in large data set (using R)

Tags: r, excel

I have multiple excel files with 8000-10000 observations each. One of the variable is date (ex: 9/12/2010), but I want to make it just say the name of the month (ex:september). Each file covers one year. I have tried manually entering the names of months in a new column, but as you can imagine it got old very fast. Is there an easy way to do this? I'll be using R to work with data, but I suppose I could use excel to make the month names before importing to R. 
I want to explore the data using 'month name' as a variable, so perhaps there is a way R can tell 9/12/2010 is september without creating a new variable?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?  Your question is a bit vague to me as it stands now.  Also, if you are planning to import data from Excel, then you can consider exporting the spreadsheets as CSV and then importing into R using `read.csv()`.

Comment: Is this what you want? `months(as.Date( "9/12/2010", "%m/%d/%Y"))`

Comment: We could try `library(readxl); library(dplyr);files <- list.files(pattern='.xlsx'); bind_rows(lapply(files, read_excel), .id=TRUE) %>% mutate(monthname= format(as.Date('9/12/2010', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%B'))`

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, I'm not sure how to include a sample. I've attempted to create a new column, looking where each month ends, and having the 'name' vector include that many reps. Ex: january<-rep("jan",713). data$month<-c(January,...,December). The 713 is the amount of oberservations in Jan. I'll try the code above and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: Also, I'll note that the example I posted above worked fine for 1 data set. It gave me exactly what I wanted, but just took too long to do for 20 sets

Comment: Ronak Shah, Your suggestion is exactly what I wanted, Thanks! I just did this :  DF$month<-months(as.Date( DF$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) and worked perfectly. I almost didnt try it, it seemed too simple.. glad I did

Answer (score 1):

supposing your dataframe is called "df" and your "Date" column is in Date format, the new column "Month" would be

```
df$Month <- format(df$Date, "%B") #full name of the month
```

or `df$Month <- format(df$Date, "%b")`#abbreviated name of the month

lemme know if that works